# django template access to models

Tags: python, django, templates

I am having an issue with templating system in Django, I am doing a Movie list app just to learn more about Django and I have already declared my models like following:

```
class Pelicula (models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    genero = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    año = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Then I have declared my view like following

```
def index(request):
    pelicula = Pelicula.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("index.html", dict(pelicula = pelicula, usuario =  request.user))
```

So as far as i know, I am not having any trouble here

Then the problem starts on my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mis peliculas favoritas</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Mis peliculas favoritas</h1>
<ol>
    {% for pelicula in pelicula.object_list %}

        <li><a href ="#">{{ pelicula.nombre }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
</ol>

<a href="agregar.html">agregar pelicula nueva</a>



</body>
</html>
```

So as you see, I am using a for loop to get all the objects in my db, I have 3, but when i run the server, the title shows up and the other link bellow named "agregar" shows up except for the movies, I am wondering if the problem is something between the "pelicula" name instead of using Pelicula as i used on declaring my model, anyway I have also changed that to Pelicula.object_list and it didn't worked anyway

I believe I am having a trouble understanding how to use the information i have through Django template tags

Thanks in advance and please forgive my grammar as I am not a native english speaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view code you have `pelicula = Pelicula.objects.all()` which creates a list of all the abjects from the database. You then send this to the template with the same name, which means all you have to do in the template is iterate over them. Try changing the template to this:

```
<h1>Mis peliculas favoritas</h1>
{% if pelicula %}
<ol>
    {% for item in pelicula %}

        <li><a href ="#">{{ item.nombre }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% else %}
didn't find any...
{% endif %}
```

Part of the confusion seems to come from the fact that the template code and the view code is separate. The template doesn't know anything about the view code. The context dictionary just sets the names that can be used in the template and in the template the only names that you have available to use are the ones that you passed to it via the dictionary. The names in the view and template here are the same in this case because you set them to be the same. They aren't the same variables though, they just have the same name. In the template `pelicula` is already a list of objects so you don't need to do anything extra to use it in the template loop.

Comment: it worked! thanks i just have the same question about what i was doing wrong, could it be posible that when i declared the variable pelicula in my views it loaded inside the template?

Comment: @AbdulHamid I edited my answer to try to explain why this happens more clearly.

Comment: thanks it worked and now i see how the template and the view code work together!